# Working with a global list in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to be able to access a list throughout my Rails project.  For simplicity's sake, this is the list I put in `environment.rb`

```
FOODS = ['CHEESE', 'EGGS', 'ORANGES']
```

I want every file to have access to this constant, but at the same time I'm worried that some file might mess up the list for all the other files by doing something that only it particularly needs, e.g.: `FOODS.push("TEMPORARY_FOOD")`

What's the right way to make this list globally accessible?  Should I be using `.freeze`, or should I be using some other method than `environment.rb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ruby constant by convention is not meant to be modified. Using `.freeze` is fine, but remember that it does not stop the constant from being redefined,

```
FOODS = ['ANOTHER', 'ARRAY']
```

The constant should already be accessible globally if you defined it in `environment.rb`. A better place to put the constant initialization in a file in config/initializers - unless you need it in environment.rb - makes upgrading environment.rb (Rails upgrade easier)

Comment: I think if you define as ::FOODS it will be defined in the global scope (if that exists), based on a Ryan Bates screen cast at RailCasts

Answer (score 0):

If only the view files need the FOODS array, you can put it in the application_helper file. If also models need it you can merge it with other arrays:

FOOD + ["Bananas"]

(there are a million more ways to do this).